# How to show multiple existing markers from google maps sorting by sports category?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an android application where I need to show all existing sport courts from a specific zone, these courts need to be marked with a pin and in the moment when I click the pin, some information about the court will be displayed.

How to get those existing `markers` from **Google Maps** automatically, without manually inserting for every place the exact location (longitude and latitude).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for **GOOGLE PLACES SDK** , it allows you to get all places by category referred [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/supported_types#table1) . and also with [nearby option](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests)

and once you get your Place information through [Place ID](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/place-id) , then you can show it on `marker` `infowindow`

**Note** that using **GOOGLE PLACES SDK** is not for free